# C++ Problems with Class Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, rgb

//#Program is to read in ppm file and display it in command prompt#
//#Also it must be able to take two pictures and superimpose one over the other#

```
#include "Image.h"
#include "P3Loader.h"
#include "P6Loader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

// sets height and width to zero

```
 Image::Image()
    {
        width = height = 0;
    }
```

// copies the Image class

```
Image::Image(const Image& copy)
{
    width = copy.width;
    height = copy.height;
    loader = copy.loader;

    pixels = new Color[copy.height];
    for(int i = 0; i < copy.height; i++)
    {
        pixels = new Color[copy.width];
    }

    for(int h = 0; h < copy.height; h++)
    {
        for(int w = 0; w < copy.width; w++)
        {
            pixels[h*w] = copy.pixels[h*w];
        }
    }
}
```

// zeros all pixels out

```
 Image::~Image()
    {
        delete[] pixels;
    }
```

//loads the file that user selects in main

```
void Image::loadimage(string filename)
{
    ifstream picture;
    string magic_number;
    //enter filename

    picture.open(filename);
    if(picture.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error... FIle not opened" << endl;
    }

    picture >> magic_number;

    if(magic_number == "P3")
    {
        loader = new P3Loader;
    }
    else if (magic_number == "P6")
    {
        loader = new P6Loader;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not a vaild Format" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

// saves image in temp file

```
void Image::saveimage(string filename)
{
    ifstream imageFile;
    string magic_number;
    char *temp;

    imageFile.open(filename);

    imageFile >> magic_number >> width >> height;
    imageFile.get(); 

    temp = new char[width*height*3];

    // read in the image data to temp
    imageFile.read(temp,width*height*3); 

    pixels = new Color[width*height];
    for (int i=0; i<width*height; i++) 
    {
        unsigned char red = temp[i*3];
        unsigned char green = temp[i*3+1];
        unsigned char blue = temp[i*3+2];
        Color[i].r = red; // *Error: expected an identifier: expression must have a constant val*
        Color.[i].g = green; // *Error: expected an identifier* 
        Color[i].b = blue; // *Error:expected an identifier: expression must have a constant val* 
    }

}
```

//operator= overload

```
 Image Image::operator=(const Image& other)
    {
        height = other.height;
        width = other.width;
        loader = other.loader;
        pixels = other.pixels;

        return *this;
    }
```

// function to impose one picture upon another

```
 void superimpose(const Image& ontop, Color mask)
    {

    }
```

// *gets the files height*

```
int getheight()
{
    int height;
    int width;
    string magic_number;

    ifstream picture;
    picture.open(filename);

    picture >> magic_number >> width >> height;
    return height; // send it back w, h
}
```

// *gets the file type and width*

```
int getwidth()
{
    int width;

    string magic_number;
    ifstream picture;
    picture.open(filename);
    picture >> magic_number >> width;
    return width; // send it back w, h
}
```

Color[i].r = red; // *Error: expected an identifier: expression must have a constant val*
        Color.[i].g = green; // *Error: expected an identifier* 
        Color[i].b = blue; // *Error:expected an identifier: expression must have a con
// Thank you in advance if you can help me

Comment: So what was the question / What problems are you encountering?

Comment: What did you discover when you used the *debugger* and singly executed each line?

Comment: Im getting an error in the saveimage function, but i dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Color for the array instead of the array you made "pixels." Change these lines:

```
Color[i].r = red; // *Error: expected an identifier: expression must have a constant val*
Color.[i].g = green; // *Error: expected an identifier* 
Color[i].b = blue; // *Error:expected an identifier: expression must have a constant val*
```

to:

```
pixels[i].r = red; // *Error: expected an identifier: expression must have a constant val*
pixels[i].g = green; // *Error: expected an identifier* 
pixels[i].b = blue; // *Error:expected an identifier: expression must have a constant val*
```